# How to install os

Tags: boot, partitioning

I have a VAIO SVE14123CNB presently running with Window 10(upgraded from 8). I want to completely switch to ubuntu 15.10( possessing a live USB). There are two partitions in the hard drive C and D. I want to  know that If I will install ubuntu by completely erasing Win 10 then what will happen to the files of another drive (D) which has all the stuffs stored. I don't have any external hard disk to make a backup.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Ubuntu it will ask you where you want to install it. One of the options should be the c partition you want to install Ubuntu on (although Ubuntu dosent give drives a letter so check which one it is) and if you install it on 'c' it might not leave the other alone. If you want to be sure you can use the 'something else' option and choose the c partition.